# How do I carry out multiple activities in one AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm building a program that will fetch the link for a file and then download the file from that location. The first part is done, that is fetching the link. Downloading the file from that same location is what I'm not able to figure out how to do. Would it be better to create another AsyncTask or can i just fit the download code in the same one too?
Also I don't know much about using multiple AsyncTasks simultaneously, so a little help would be appreciated :)
Thank you.

Comment: You can safely do both in the same task, but you should really use onProgressUpdate or something to notify your users that you fetched the link and are now starting the download. You know, to keep them up to date and not just blindly waiting for something that they don't know about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use same asynctask for both requests. After you get the link to your file. Store it in a String and then in same doInBackground method download the file. It is the best way in terms of maintaining code. If you create two asynctasks you have to manage it manually or call it in a way that don't conflict. So implement both requests in same asynctask.

Comment: Could you help me include both of them in the doInBackground method? I'm facing some problems in doing that.. I'll be posting the code as an edit to my question

Comment: No need :P
Tried coding it myself, got it! :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create another AsynTask for download task. If our task is sequence base rather than parallel than creating AsynTask for another task?? no need of it. But if want to do your task in parallel which is not possible in your case because you need link first than creating AsynTask for each task make more sense. You can run maximum 5 AysnTask at the same time.